# SSIS: Importing from flatfile, how do I custom update a column that's not in flatfile?

Tags: ssis, dataflow

Flat file has:

```
A,B
1,2
5,7
```

DB has:

```
A,B,C
1,2,null
5,7,null
```

I'd like to during import update column C with static data "3"

So it looks like:

```
A,B,C
1,2,3
5,7,3
```

Thanks in advance!

Hmm looks like this is the best solution:
[Executing the same SSIS Package with different parameters at different time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384850/executing-the-same-ssis-package-with-different-parameters-at-different-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Data Flow, you will need to add a Derived Column Component between your Flat File Source and the OLE DB Destination.

In your Derived Column, you will name it as `C` and possibly use an [Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137547.aspx). Since you say it's static, then it might be as simple as putting the literal value of `3` into the Expression column.

Comment: Maybe this will work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384850/executing-the-same-ssis-package-with-different-parameters-at-different-time

Comment: And that could work, however your question specifies you need to pass a static value to the data flow. My answer on that question addresses requirements that you never specified.