# SSIS AcquireConnection Error during Package Installation Validation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sybase, etl, bids

I'm trying to release a couple of SSIS packages to production but I'm getting an error on the AquireManager method of one of the ConnectionManagers.

**Details**:

- 2005 SSIS package extract info from Sybase and stage into SQL Server 2005 (x64)
- Connection Manager details: ***Provider***: Native OLE DB\Sybase ASE OLE DB Provider. ***Server Connection***: SQL Server Authentication. ***DelayValidation***: true
- Server Confg: Windows Server 2008 R2 (64bits)
- Deployment Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Packages\SSIS
- Getting the following error when SSIS Installation Wizard is doing the final Validation:

> Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTAQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AquireConnection method call to the connection manager "" failed with error 0x0202009.
>
> Error: component "Database Table" (1798) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

[image]

Any clue of what I'm missing on the release process? Anything really stupid in front of my eyes I'm not realizing?. All the contributions are welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You need to run/validate your package in 32 bit mode

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13092260/181965
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8790987/181965
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13960063/181965
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8386338/181965

Comment: @billinkc - All of those posts refers to Excel sources but I'm using Sybase source. Additionally, my SSIS is being raised from TSQL sp, no SQL Agent.

Comment: Yes, those all cover Excel but I link them because Excel and the Sybase drivers (that I've seen) are all 32 bit. Development in Visual Studio/BIDS/SSDT will be in 32 bit mode. When you deploy/run somewhere, the default will be to run in 64 bit mode. The drivers you define for 32 bit mode won't be available for 64 bit space and vice versa.

Comment: Also, ensure you have the Sybase driver installed on the target server and it's a spot on match for what you have on your machine. I've seen point differences in drivers result in invalid packages