# How to pass parameter to SSIS Job through command line

Tags: ssis, sqlcmd, sql-agent-job

I am executing a job from command line (sqlcmd).

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = @job_name
```

How can I pass a parameter at the time of job execution through the command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing the same SSIS Package with different parameters at different time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384850/executing-the-same-ssis-package-with-different-parameters-at-different-time)

Answer (score 0):

There is not direct way to pass parameter to "msdb.dbo.sp_start_job"

So we can  think indirect way to do something.

You could create a table to hold the parameters, such as:

```
  CREATE TABLE SQLAgentJobParms
       (job_id uniqueidentifier,
        groupparm int,
        parameter_name nvarchar(100),
        parameter_value nvarchar(100),
         used_datetime datetime NULL);
```

The groupparm is way to identify a group of parameters intended to go together.  One you have used them you can update the used_datetime.

You would then need to write your job to select the necessary values from this table in order to use them as parameters for the steps in your job.

EXEC sp_start_job